# Jquery - making flickering light, while-setTimeout issue

Tags: jquery

What am I trying to do is to make something like neon-style flickering light.
This function is not finished yet:

```
function callFlicker($target, size, color1, color2, color3){
        var fastInterval    = getRandomInt(1, 5) * 30;
        var longInterval    = getRandomInt(1, 20) * 100;
        var afIntervals     = getRandomInt(3, 6);
        var alIntervals     = getRandomInt(1, 3);
        var getTColor       = $target.css('color'); 
        var TargetLight = $target.css({
            '-webkit-box-shadow'    : '0 0px '+size+'px rga('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
            'box-shadow'            : '0 0px '+size+'px rgb('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
            'color'                 : getTColor,
            'opacity'               : 1
        });
        var TargetDark = $target.css({
            '-webkit-box-shadow'    : '0 0px '+size+'px rga('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
            'box-shadow'            : '0 0px '+size+'px rgb('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
            'opacity'               : 0.2
        });

        while(afIntervals > 0) {
            afIntervals -= 1;           
            setTimeout(function(){
                $target.css({
                    '-webkit-box-shadow'    : '0 0px '+size+'px rga('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
                    'box-shadow'            : '0 0px '+size+'px rgb('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
                    'color'                 : getTColor,
                    'opacity'               : 1
                });
            }, fastInterval);           
            setTimeout(function(){
                $target.css({
                    '-webkit-box-shadow'    : '0 0px '+size+'px rga('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
                    'box-shadow'            : '0 0px '+size+'px rgb('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
                    'opacity'               : 0.2
                });
            }, fastInterval*2);
        }   
};
```

What's the logic behind this, `$target` is object on which flicker will be placed, `size` is the size of box-shadow, `color(1,2,3)` is color of box-shadow.
`fastInterval` is necessary to determine how fast interval between `afIntervals` will occur, if you remember how neon signs flicker when you turning them on, it's just a few fast flickers (`afIntervals` here) and one or two long in the end (`alIntervals` here), that's what I'm trying to achieve with all of these.

So, getting closer to the issue, I don't know how exactly I should iterate through all intervals, I've tried `while`, and `setTimeout` runs only once, but I want them to happen all the time, `while afIntervals > 0`. How could be this done?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m33ru/ (note: you probably need to hit "run" few times to see that code actually works for first iteration)

P.S. Probably not the best idea with `var TargetLight, TargetDark` but I don't know for now how could I store in `var` Json data to load it later.

Comment: Not really sure I understand what you want/need but maybe this gives some insights? http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/m33ru/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript code does not work. Here is the correct code. You can see it working here. http://jsfiddle.net/m33ru/4/

You could use setInterval() as suggested in the other answer, but then your animation continues indefinitely. My solution works if you want to animate only a finite number of times.

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function callFlicker($target, size, color1, color2, color3){
    var fastInterval    = getRandomInt(1, 5) * 30;
    var longInterval    = getRandomInt(1, 20) * 100;
    var afIntervals     = getRandomInt(3, 6);
    var alIntervals     = getRandomInt(1, 3);
    var getTColor       = $target.css('color'); 
    var TargetLight = $target.css({
        '-webkit-box-shadow'    : '0 0px '+size+'px rga('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
        'box-shadow'            : '0 0px '+size+'px rgb('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
        'color'                 : getTColor,
        'opacity'               : 1
    });
    var TargetDark = $target.css({
        '-webkit-box-shadow'    : '0 0px '+size+'px rga('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
        'box-shadow'            : '0 0px '+size+'px rgb('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
        'opacity'               : 0.2
    });
    console.log(afIntervals+' '+alIntervals);       

    var lightup = function(){
            $target.css({
                '-webkit-box-shadow'    : '0 0px '+size+'px rga('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
                'box-shadow'            : '0 0px '+size+'px rgb('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
                'color'                 : getTColor,
                'opacity'               : 1
            });
            setTimeout(lightdown, fastInterval);
    };
    var lightdown = function(){
            $target.css({
                '-webkit-box-shadow'    : '0 0px '+size+'px rga('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
                'box-shadow'            : '0 0px '+size+'px rgb('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
                'opacity'               : 0.2
            });
            afIntervals--;
            if (afIntervals > 0) setTimeout(lightup, fastInterval);
    };
    setTimeout(lightup, fastInterval);
};

$(document).ready(function(){   
    callFlicker($('.flicker'), 25, 68, 192, 255);       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use setInterval() method instead of setTimeout()

```
    while(afIntervals > 0) {
        afIntervals -= 1;           
        setInterval(function(){
            $target.css({
                '-webkit-box-shadow'    : '0 0px '+size+'px rga('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
                'box-shadow'            : '0 0px '+size+'px rgb('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
                'color'                 : getTColor,
                'opacity'               : 1
            });
        }, fastInterval);           
        setInterval(function(){
            $target.css({
                '-webkit-box-shadow'    : '0 0px '+size+'px rga('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
                'box-shadow'            : '0 0px '+size+'px rgb('+color1+','+color2+','+color3+')',
                'opacity'               : 0.2
            });
        }, fastInterval*2);
        console.log(afIntervals);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m33ru/3/